# Run Restfuse Test using Maven

Tags: maven, netbeans

I'm trying to run a Restfuse test using NetBeans.

NetBeans is using the following Maven command to run the Restfuse Test:

```
mvn -Dtest=com.mycompany.RequestTest -DfailIfNoTests=false test-compile surefire:test
```

However, the HttpTest method didn't get called:

```
    @RunWith(HttpJUnitRunner.class)
    public class RequestTest {

        @Rule
        public Destination destination;
        @Context
        private Response response;

        public MatchRequestTest() throws UnknownHostException {
            this.destination = getDestination();
            this.callbackHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        }

        @HttpTest(method = Method.GET, path = "/request")
        public void matchRequest() {
            assertOk(response);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefix your class name with "Test" i.e. TestRequestTest.